# robot framework database library pymssql module error on scalar variable

Tags: robotframework

i have used the keyword Execute Sql Script the sql script can be executed, but the content contains parameter declaration which looks like something like this:

**declare @itemNo nvarchar (10),

@itemId int

[insert script]

set @itemId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

[insert script with @itemId used as one of the parameter]**

then when i execute this in ride, it always says that i have to declare @itemid. tried this also with adodbapi and it is the same error.

when i run the script in ms sql server, it runs fine, no errors.

has anyone encountered this? Any workaround? thanks!